# Implementing Theming in React Application

Tags: css, reactjs, themes

I got a requirement from my client that we need to have custom themes in our react application.

Where user can select one of the available themes of his choice which will change some css attribute like font-color, font-family etc.

Right now I apply css rules to my application using `className` attribute.

I tried searching some of the ways of implementing the same and found one way that is having alternate css

```
<link rel="stylesheet"           href="main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet alternate" href="light.css" id="light" title="Light">
<link rel="stylesheet alternate" href="dark.css"  id="dark"  title="Dark">

<script>
function enableStylesheet (node) {
  node.rel = 'stylesheet';
}

function disableStylesheet (node) {
  node.rel = 'alternate stylesheet';
}
</script>
```

And toggle `rel` value based on user selection.

Can any one suggest me any other way of achieving the same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your usage is the correct way of implementing. But what if you've numerous theme? Loading all the css files will hamper the website. So, I would suggest you to update the source instead of loading all css files and enabling/disabling them.

```
node.ref = 'dark.css';
```

This way, you're requiring the css file only when in use. Once, the file is being used, next time it's cached. So no need to worry about them later. Obviously, it might take some time and may impact on performance if the filesize is huge, at initial use. Even though the best thing is that you don't need to wait for all.

---

**But wait!!!**

You're using react. React provides us [context api](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) and I would obviously utilize this in such scenario. Here's an excerpted example:

```
import {ThemeContext, themes} from './theme-context';
import ThemeTogglerButton from './theme-toggler-button';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.toggleTheme = () => {
      this.setState(state => ({
        theme:
          state.theme === themes.dark
            ? themes.light
            : themes.dark,
      }));
    };

    // State also contains the updater function so it will
    // be passed down into the context provider
    this.state = {
      theme: themes.light,
      toggleTheme: this.toggleTheme,
    };
  }

  render() {
    // The entire state is passed to the provider
    return (
      <ThemeContext.Provider value={this.state}>
        <Content />
      </ThemeContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

function Content() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ThemeTogglerButton />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.root);
```

Similar concept can be implemented using [redux](https://redux.js.org) and with logger information to make our work easy.

Comment: Thanks @Bhojendra for your suggestion, but some of the css rules are using !important. Can you please suggest how we can override those using Context Api.

Comment: That matters with css not react.

Comment: Got your point @Bhojendra, so are you suggesting changing css is the only solution to encounter this situation?